# Dynamics AX 2012, filtering out data in queries by using business logis

Tags: methods, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamic-queries

I am using Dynamics AX 2012 R2.

I am creating a query for a view where I have to filter out data based on predefined business logic.

For example, I have one table in my query (simplified) and I want to be able to filter out rows in the view where the sum of value1 and value2 and value3 are equal to zero.

I cannot use the query range in the query since I have around 20 values (columns) that I need to check before I filter out the rows. It doesn´t allow it, it only handles around 10 values or so

I dont like creating a "full" view, e.g. view with all rows then a view method with the business logic that has to be applied to filter out the rows and then a query based on that view where the rows are filter out.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a [computed view field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx) for the sum of your fields?

> I dont like creating a "full" view, e.g. view with all rows then a
>   view method with the business logic that has to be applied to filter
>   out the rows and then a query based on that view where the rows are
>   filter out.

You are cutting out a useful method (but you need not make any queries).

Another approach would be to make a redundant field in your base table with your 20 fields added.

Update: Please read [View Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314551.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Jan :)

The reason why I don´t want to create a view with all the data is that this particular view contains transactions and therefore large amount of data and I only need a small part of the data.

Perhaps the only way is to create a redundant field in the base table. That would work.

I just find it a bit strange that I am unable to filter out data with complex business logic at the query level.. or maybe it is possible but I just dont know how..

Comment: Views are excellent for providing "small part of the data". That is basically what they are made for! Read View Basics.